# Filtering from a Pandas dataframe using conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I'm having the following issue while filtering this pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': [2020,2020,2019,2019, 2019,2020, 2020],'MONTH': [7,6,6,7, 2, 1, 2],'WEEK': [2,2,3,3, 2, 1, 2],'SALES': [45357, 30000, 2858, 10500, 3321, 23434, 2233]})
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> df1
   YEAR  MONTH  WEEK  SALES
0  2020      7     2  45357
1  2020      6     2  30000
2  2019      6     3   2858
3  2019      7     3  10500
4  2019      2     2   3321
5  2020      1     1  23434
6  2020      2     2   2233
>>>
```

I'm using this code to filter the dataframe:

```
df1[(df1['YEAR'] != 2020) & (df1['MONTH'] != 7)]
```

I wanted to remove the rows where the year was 2020 and the month 7, but instead this code gives me a dataframe with the year 2019 and the months 6 and 2. What am I doing wrong? Will I need to create a new column with Month and year?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with R so please don't tag it. Also, there's no need to have your question title all in CAPS

Comment: Anyway, your code cannot leave you just with the month `8` because it doesn't even exist in your dataset

Comment: Is this what you want? `df1.query("YEAR!=2020 | MONTH!=7")`?

Comment: Sorry for the Caps and tagging R @roganjosh , I'm still learning my way over here.

Comment: @NelsonGon I didn't want to use query, but another user answered with what I wanted, thanks tho!

Comment: there are no months == 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `year=2020` and `month=7`, you can do these:

```
df1 = df1[~((df1['YEAR'] == 2020) & (df1['MONTH'] == 7))]
```

or

```
df1 = df1[(df1['YEAR'] != 2020) | (df1['MONTH'] != 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic here is a little bit off

```
df1[~((df1['YEAR'] == 2020) & (df1['MONTH'] == 7))]
   YEAR  MONTH  WEEK  SALES
1  2020      6     2  30000
2  2019      6     3   2858
3  2019      7     3  10500
4  2019      2     2   3321
5  2020      1     1  23434
6  2020      2     2   2233
```

Or change `&` to `|`

```
df1[(df1['YEAR'] != 2020) | (df1['MONTH'] != 7)]
   YEAR  MONTH  WEEK  SALES
1  2020      6     2  30000
2  2019      6     3   2858
3  2019      7     3  10500
4  2019      2     2   3321
5  2020      1     1  23434
6  2020      2     2   2233
```

Answer (score 0):

For the months part you're excluding all months = 7. I think changing it to  `df1['MONTH'] == 7` will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you can use `loc`:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'YEAR': [2020,2020,2019,2019, 2019,2020, 2020],
                    'MONTH': [7,6,6,7, 2, 1, 2],
                    'WEEK': [2,2,3,3, 2, 1, 2],
                    'SALES': [45357, 30000, 2858, 10500, 3321, 23434, 2233]})

print(df1.loc[(df1['YEAR']!=2020)|(df1['MONTH']!=7)])
```

Output:

```
   YEAR  MONTH  WEEK  SALES
1  2020      6     2  30000
2  2019      6     3   2858
3  2019      7     3  10500
4  2019      2     2   3321
5  2020      1     1  23434
6  2020      2     2   2233
```